# Linq to sql - left outer Join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, left-join

I have Three Table without assosiatated  as Follows

1. Clients
2. Bank
3. Country

Some clients they don't Have bank Details so I need to get all the Cleint Info Who has the bank and Who hasn't the bank, and same as country info

I know It's "left outer join" method. how its in the Linq to sql

vb.net code Please

Comment: accept answer if it work for you

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
var query = 
    from order in dc.Orders
    from vendor 
    in dc.Vendors
         .Where(v => v.Id == order.VendorId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from status 
    in dc.Status
         .Where(s => s.Id == order.StatusId)
         .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Order = order, Vendor = vendor, Status = status } 
    //Vendor and Status properties will be null if the left join is null
```

[LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ To SQL](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know your SQL query, create your left join and execute it through [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net).

It can then output the corresponding LINQ query.

Best of luck.

Comment: is it possible to convert SQL query in to Linq using above LinqPAD

Comment: No, only the other way round as far as I know.